# Criar uma matriz sem repetição dos valores do argumento data

Tags: r, matriz

Olá, tenho o seguinte código

```
M <- matrix(data = c(1,2,3,4,5), nrow = 5, ncol = 5, T)
```

Ele produz a seguinte saída:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]    1    2    3    4    5
[3,]    1    2    3    4    5
[4,]    1    2    3    4    5
[5,]    1    2    3    4    5
```

Desejo que a matriz seja criada de forma que utilize os valores do array fornecido como data, porém que nao repita o array em seguida, mas sim complete os valores nao fornecidos com `NA`, ficando da seguinte forma:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Sei que tem como fazer isso criando uma matriz com `data = NA` e depois fazer um loop na matriz, mas queria saber uma maneira mais rapida e mais eficiente de se fazer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isto que ocorre em `R` é chamado de [reciclagem](https://excelkingdom.blogspot.com/2018/01/what-recycling-of-vector-elements-in-r.html) (repetição de valores para completar o vetor). Você pode resolver esta situação ajustando o vetor fora da função `matrix` ou dentro dela. Aqui vão as duas formas:

**Ajuste do vetor fora da função**

```
x <- 1:5
```

Isso significa que `x` vai de `1` a `5`. Agora, considere isso:

```
length(x) <- prod(dim(matrix(x, ncol = 5, nrow = 5)))
```

Ou simplesmente isso:

```
length(x) <- prod(5, 5)
```

Ou isso:

```
length(x) <- 25
```

Isso significa que o comprimento do vetor é igual a `5x5 = 25`. Mas, como x vai de `1` a `5`, o vetor será completato com `NA`s:

```
x

#[1]  1  2  3  4  5 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Agora, coloque este vetor como parâmetro no argumento `data`:

```
M <- matrix(data = x, nrow = 5, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE)

M

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4    5
# [2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# [3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# [4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# [5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

**Ajuste do vetor dentro da função**

Outra opção é criar os dados dentro da função `matrix`. Assim:

```
matrix(data = c(1:5, rep(c(NA), times = 20)), nrow = 5, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4    5
# [2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# [3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# [4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# [5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Além da resposta bastante completa do @neves, queria chamar a atenção para algo que está na pergunta (ênfase minha):

> Sei que tem como fazer isso criando uma matriz com `data = NA` e depois
>   **fazer um loop** na matriz, mas queria saber uma maneira mais rapida e
>   mais eficiente de se fazer.

O R é uma linguagem vetorizada, neste caso, tal como em muitos outros,não é necessário fazer loops.

```
M <- matrix(NA, nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
M[1, ] <- 1:5

M
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
#[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#[4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```